# How to prevent CKEditor translating accented letters to their HTML codes?

Tags: internationalization, ckeditor, diacritics

I'd like to configure CKEditor to save accented letters as they are, and don't change them  to their HTML equivalent, since I'm working work with UTF8 anyway.

Where and what do I need to set to achieve this?

***Example:***

**Current:** entered: `áéíóúöőüű` source: `<p>&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute;&ouml;ő&uuml;ű</p>`

**Wished for:** entered: `áéíóúöőüű` source: `<p>áéíóúöőüű</p>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its a config setting I think its [entities](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities) though it could be one of the neighboring config options that you want, I'm not 100% but it should put you in the right direciton

Comment: Thanks fo the link! This is what I was looking for: short, concise and to the point.